# React-Native Handle push notification with react-navigation

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I need to handle push notifications and I am using `onesignal` for it.
Currently I am handling push notifications in my home screen and I am using `react-navigation`.

```
 componentDidMount() {
        OneSignal.addEventListener('received', this.onReceived);
        OneSignal.addEventListener('opened', this.onOpened);

    }
 componentWillUnmount() {
        // OneSignal.removeEventListener('received');
        // OneSignal.removeEventListener('opened');
    }

onReceived(notification) {
    console.log('Notification received: ', notification);
}
onOpened = (data) => {
    const { notification: { payload } } = data;
    if (payload.additionalData) {
        if (payload.additionalData.params) {
            this.props.navigation.navigate({
                routeName: payload.additionalData.route,
                params: payload.additionalData.params,
                key: payload.notificationID
            });
        }
    }
}
```

With this code I am able to navigate to a route specified in the data packet of notifications.
Now the problem I face is, I have a screen and I want to refresh my page, for example call `getData();` of that component.
With this approach I am able to navigate to that screen and if I get the notification while I am on that screen. with the help of key, I can navigate to that screen.

Lets say I am going to OrderDetail screen and when I get the notification, It navigates to Order Detail,
`Home Screen --> Order Detail`
 and now If I am inside `OrderDetail` and if I get the notification, It would be

`Home Screen ---> Order Detail ---> Order Detail`
 ...and so on'
How can I handle push notifications in this case?

Comment: Handle notifications on a parent component. Like App Root or some wrapper which take cares only notifications.

Comment: then how would i navigate to a screen? and refresh the data if i am on the screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly... handle the push notification differently on **Home** and **Detail** pages.

Say,on **Home** page, listen to notification when `didFocus`, and remove the listener when `willBlur`. So the handler will action only when a user is on **Home**. And navigate (route) to "Detail" in the notification handler of **Home** page.

Likewise, on **Detail** page, listen to notification when `didFocus`, and remove the listener when `willBlur`. While the handler simply updates the content when notification is received.

---edit---

Home:

```
constructor() {
  this.props.navigation.addListener(
    'willBlur',() => {
      OneSignal.removeEventListener('received');
      OneSignal.removeEventListener('opened');
    }
  );

  this.props.navigation.addListener(
    'didFocus',() => {
      OneSignal.addEventListener('received');
      OneSignal.addEventListener('opened');
    }
  );
}
// handler implementation is the same
```

Detail:

```
//same lifecycle implementation
// but different handler
onOpened = (data) => {
const { notification: { payload } } = data;
if (payload.additionalData) {
    if (payload.additionalData.params) {
        this.setState(paramsUsedByDetail: payload.additionalData.params);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: When i do this, for some reason my removeListeners don't work...the listeners in my home screens are active, they only dont work while i am on detail page...when on other pages...my home listeners are active....and maybe in detail page too....but its just over writing the home listeners

Comment: Do you think it's caused by your existing add listener in `componentDidMount`? Are `willBlur` and  `didFocus` are handled in constructor?

Comment: with this approach i would have to add a notification listener to every screen, is there a efficient solution?

Comment: For sure. I would recommend Flux (try google "Flux for beginners", there is a good article by blog.andrewray.me) which is designed for this purpose I believe.